# Adding custom HTTP error and exceptions to flask

Tags: http, flask, werkzeug

How would I go about adding a custom HTTP error? From what I understand error codes in the 6XX and 7XX class can be used for that purpose, but Flask doesn't let me handle these errors as it says that this(601) isn't a recognized HTTP error.

EDIT:
This is the correct Code:-

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

@errors.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def error_601(HTTPException):
    return render_template('errors/601.html'), 601


class No_results_found(HTTPException):
    code = 601
    description = '<p>No_results_found.</p>'

errors.register_error_handler(No_results_found, error_601)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `@app.errorhandler(HTTPException)` before `error_601`

Documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#registering

Comment: thanks for the tip, I missed the decorator from the docs.